# No module named ipapi

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I was trying to add some custom completers for some of my functions in an IPython notebook as per suggestions from http://wiki.ipython.org/index.php?title=Cookbook/Custom_completers

When the code tries to load ipapi from IPython, it gets an "ImportError: No module named ipapi"

Any ideas? I saw some bugreports on this for earlier versions, should be fixed in 0.13.1 which I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems ipapi moved into Ipython.core

Calling import Ipython.core.ipapi works without issues.

Comment: ipapi is deprecated (has been since 0.11). Any references to is should be considered a bug in the docs.

Comment: Thanks Min! any alternate method to write custom tab completers?

Comment: ipapi is just an old name for what is now called `get_ipython()`.

Comment: Thanks Min! I will use the new name. I am editing the cookbook page to replace the old ref to new one.

Comment: I have edited a portion the cookbook page linked above. @minrk, Can you have someone more versed with the api do further cleanup?